# MySQL - Arrange a table so that it shrinks as much as possible?

Tags: mysql

I'm a newbie and I have +10 million articles(200 to 1000 words) in a InnoDB table. I use this to select them:

```
SELECT article,title,other_fields from table where id=123;
```

There is no full-text search or any updates on `article` field.

How can I arrange the table so that the table size shrinks as much as possible. I'm happy with a little performance tradeoff. I'm sorry for the vague question but I couldn't find any answers online.

PS: There are inserts and updates on `table`, should I put `article` and `id` to a seperate table?

Comment: Hi, 1. What are the references between ID column and Article column, one (ID) to one(article) OR one to many)?. 2.for the performance issue : do you know if there is any INDEX on id column ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's general recommendations for keeping table size small

- Try `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED` when creating InnoDB tables. There will be impact on writes.
- Use index with prefix
- Use `OPTIMIZE TABLE` often if it gets many DELETE/UPDATE's

Normalizing tables would actually result in bigger overall size, but less. It MAY help with caching, though.